# h2o always returns memory address instead of actual content

Tags: python, h2o

My h2o code used to return useful information like printing table and metrics but for some reason now always returns memory address.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import h2o
from h2o.estimators import H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator
h2o.init()

df = pd.read_csv('winequality-white.csv', sep=';')
df.loc[df.quality <= 6, 'quality'] = 0
df.loc[df.quality > 6, 'quality'] = 1
hf = h2o.H2OFrame(df)
print(hf.head())
```

output:

```
Parse progress: |████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| (done) 100%
<h2o.frame.H2OFrame object at 0x0000025D22121EB0>
```

```
wine_split = hf.split_frame(ratios = [0.8], seed = 1234)
wine_train = wine_split[0] 
wine_test = wine_split[1]  
gbm_default = H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(seed = 1234, family='binomial', alpha=1)
gbm_default.train(x = features, y = 'quality', training_frame = wine_train)
print(gbm_default)
```

output:

```
██████████████████████████████████████████████████████| (done) 100%
<h2o.estimators.glm.H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator object at 0x0000025D74E225E0>
```

I have tried shutting down everything and restarting everything but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify the version of h2o you use and how you use it (are you using  IPython/bpython/Jupyter or some IDE like Spyder/PyCharm)?

Since you have `pandas` installed you can use `print(hf.head().as_data_frame())` to convert the "head" of the hf to `pandas` and render it using `pandas`.

For the model object you can try `gbm_default.show()` or
`gbm_default.get_summary()` (or `gbm_default.summary()` if you have older versions).

Comment: I use h2o 3.34 (I cannot update it), and run it on Jupyter (Python 3.8).